# Having issues drawing with my python class

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to create a program that simulates a horse race, my issue is when i draw with Tkinter i get a blank canvas. I'm sure its some obvious mistake but i can't find it. Any help?

```
class Horse ():

    def __init__ (self, color, number, slot):
        self.xPos = 0
        self.yPos = self.xPos - 59
        self.move = 0
        self.slot = slot
        self.size = 40
        self.color = color
        self.number = number

    def horseMove (self):
        self.Erase()
        self.move= random.randint(20,80)
        self.xPos = self.xPos + self.move
        self.Draw()
        myCanvas.update()
        return self.xPos

    def Erase (self):
        myCanvas.create_rectangle (self.xPos, self.yPos, self.xPos + 75, self.yPos +    40, fill = 'white', outline ='white')

    def Draw (self):
        myCanvas.create_oval (self.xPos, self.yPos, self.xPos + 75, self.yPos + 40, fill = color)
        myCanvas.create_text (self.xPos + 35, self.yPos, text = self.number, fill = 'blue', font = ("Times","17"))
        time.sleep (0.5)
```

This is my class code

```
Horses= []
slot=0
for i in range (0,3):
    number=input("what is the horses number: ")
    color=input("what is the horses color: ")
    slot += 1
    animal=Horse(color, number, slot)
    Horses.append(animal)

import random
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
myCanvas = Canvas (root, width =1000, height=1000, background='white')
myCanvas.pack()

while True:
    for i in range (0,len(Horses)):
        animal.horseMove()
```

This is my mainline

Comment: You have quite a few problems, ie `myCanvas` is not defined on the Horse class, a infinite loop that will lock up your program and the `for i in range (0,len(Horses)):` loop that does not use `i`. Start with something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great many problems in your code. To tackle the specific question of why you get a blank canvas, it's because you're drawing the horse objects off of the screen because of this line:

```
    self.yPos = self.xPos - 59
```

`self.xPos` is zero, so `self.yPos` is -59, but the default top y coordinate is 0, so you're drawing off screen.

There are many other problems in your code. Most troubling is that you're calling `time.sleep` which does exactly what you think it does -- it causes your whole program to sleep. You should *never* call `time.sleep` in the main thread of a GUI.

You are (attempting to) delete and recreate the objects for each moment of the race. However, you aren't actually erasing anything, you're just hiding it. You should call the `delete` method of the canvas to erase objects. Also, are you aware that the canvas has a `move` method that can be used to move items? So, you don't need to delete and recreate them -- just draw the horse once, then call `move` to move it across the screen.

Finally, you're doing an infinite loop and in that loop calling `update`. While this will usually work for such a simple program, it's the wrong approach to doing animation with Tkinter. A good rule of thumb is that you should never directly call `update` unless you know why you should never call `update` (and even then, it's rarely the right thing to do)

Instead of a `while True` loop, you need to write a function that moves everything once, then arrange to call it once a second (or half second, whatever). The pattern looks something like this:

```
def draw_one_frame():
    <do whatever you need to do to move each item once>
    root.after(500, self.draw_one_frame)
```

Usually you have some sort of "start" function that calls this once, and then after it causes itself to be called again. Typically you'll  have a "stop" button that calls a function to set a flag, and you check for that flag to eventually stop the animation. So, the final version looks something more like:

```
def start():
    running = True
    draw_one_frame()
def stop():
    running = False
def draw_one_frame():
    if running:
        <do whatever...>
        root.after(500, self.draw_one_frame)
```

(of course, I advocate a more OO-style approach, but I left that out to keep things simple)

Comment: how does the move method work? is there a tutorial you could link?

Comment: @ArkAngel: there's nothing to it. You simply call it, telling it what item to use and how much to move in the X and Y direction.